# Eagle 'length' of thermals to ground plane

Tags: eaglecad

I'm using Eagle pcb editor (Ver 4.15) The 'spokes' in the thermal pads to the ground plane have gotten too short.  I'm not sure how this happened.  The Eagle manual says something about changing the thermal isolate parameter in the DRC supply tab.  I've futzed with this but nothing changes.  Do I need to redraw the entire polygon with the new parameter?  (I can change the width of the 'spoke' with the polygon width command.)

Comment: On other softwares of this type (like OrCAD and CadStar) redraw/repour of each ground plane is needed for these attributes to take effect.

Comment: Right, I just discovered that.  Thanks my thermals are as they should be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using such an old version of Eagle?

Comment: @DanLaks, Grin we're cheap and it still works.  I'll have to learn KiCad someday soon.